# Google map mash up

Tags: google-maps

I want to build something like this: http://www.housingmaps.com/

I skim through a couple of tutorial about google mashup and google Map API. Does anyone know where should I start with ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start with building a database for all your data and ways of searching in it, once you have that working placing markers on maps is rather easy (see http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding for more info)

So focus on structuring your data & searching it before anything else and also ways of importing your data, hosingmaps seems to scrape craigslist.